# How to set Focus on the Form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying the get the inputted values from the user and save it on a char variable, but the problem is that nothing occurs, **and I think the problem is with the Form Focus**, this is the code, and when I run it no errors occurs, but also nothing happen. What I did wrong?

```
        char keyPressed;

        public FrmZigndSC()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Focus();
        }

        private void FrmZigndSC_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            keyPressed = e.KeyChar;

            LblResult.Text += Convert.ToString(keyPressed);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this code - Based on [`KeyPressEventHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.handled.aspx)

```
public FrmZigndSC()
{
       InitializeComponent();
       this.Focus();

       //Subscribe to event
       this.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(FrmZigndSC_KeyPress);
}


private void FrmZigndSC_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
        keyPressed = e.KeyChar;
        LblResult.Text += Convert.ToString(keyPressed);


        // Indicate the event is handled.
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Why when I run your code on my application this error occurs? `Error An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.KeyPress'`

Comment: Zignd I replaced with this.KeyPress instead FrmZigndSC.KeyPress, i ignored your design screen, but my code is correct , he is based on KeyPress.

Comment: That's made @Zignd, i approved

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce it in an empty little Windows Forms project. This code worked just fine without the `Shown` event handler:

```
public partial class FrmZigndSC : Form
{
    public FrmZigndSC()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.KeyPress += (s, e) => this.LblResult.Text += e.KeyChar.ToString();

        // this might be a solution, but i did not need it
        this.Shown += (s, e) => this.Activate();
    }
}
```

You could try to use `this.Activate()` anyway and see if it helps. If you got **other input controls** such as **text boxes** on your form, try setting the form's `KeyPreview` property to true.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to recieve a key notification from the application'e mesage pipeline, relaying on focus of the element, in this case, make architecture fragile. You can not gurantee that from other forms in your app that one would be focused, or the form is nto covered by some control that absorbes that event. You can not forse to a form having a focus, cause it's completely bad UX design (not very sure even if this is possible to implement in 100% working way).

What you *can* do it, instead, is declare class derived from [IMessageFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter.aspx):

```
public class MessageFilter : IMessageFilter
{
        const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
        const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;

        public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
        {
            // Intercept KEY down message
            Keys keyCode = (Keys)(int)m.WParam & Keys.KeyCode;

            if ((m.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN)
            {
                 //get key pressed  

                 return true;
            }        
            else
            {
                return false;
            }


        }
}
```

and after *register* it within your application:

```
MessageFilter filter = new MessageFilter(); //init somewhere 


Application.AddMessageFilter(filter ); // add 

..... 

//on application end don't forget to remove it 
Application.RemoveMessageFilter(filter );
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the FocusManager instead of this.Focus() should do the trick!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I Think the problem is that when you have differenct controls on your Form that catch ketpressed. I had the same probmel with an DateTimePicker on my control.

Try to delete all of them and then try it, it will work. And from that point add the controls again to see which on is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have given is working fine for me. Set the startup page as FrmZigndSC and try again.